# How to skip the welcome page and start Strapi right from /admin (login) page?

Tags: deployment, strapi

I've successfully deployed a Strapi app to a VPS (Ubuntu, nginx, etc.) and it works fine. What I want to do now is to redirect a user right to the /admin page. I mean now, after entering `https://strapi.my-domain.com` in a browser's address panel, user gets the standard welcome page like so:
[welcome page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrfuO.png)
But I want a user to see Strapi's /admin page right after he/she entered `https://strapi.my-domain.com` in a browser's address panel. Could someone please give any advice how to do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this is my solution, changing directly to meta is bad approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77029995/strapi-how-to-redirect-to-different-route-after-login-v4

Answer (score 0):

I was exploring strapi v4 document for similar problem and found this solution.

Redirecting landing page to admin panel
If you do not wish to have the default landing page mounted on / you can create a custom ./public/index.html using the sample code below to automatically redirect to your admin panel.

✋ CAUTION
This sample configuration expects that the admin panel is accessible on /admin. If you used one of the above configurations to change this to /dashboard you will also need to adjust this sample configuration.

Path — ./public/index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/admin'" />
  </head>
</html>
```

Source: [Strapi v4 Document](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment/optional-software/nginx-proxy.html#redirecting-landing-page-to-admin-panel)