# Strapi how to redirect to different route after login, v4+

Tags: node.js, redirect, routes, strapi, koa

I am working with Strapi, and I am trying to modify the default behaviour after a user logs in. By default, Strapi redirects users to the /admin welcome page, which includes various links and information. However, I want users to be redirected directly to a specific tables page within the admin panel after login. I attempted to change middleware, but it did not work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after some hassle some customisation I had to make.

the solution below changing all the default routes to /admin/content-manager
but that fully depends what default route can be redirected

> in src/middlewares/admin-redirect.js

```
module.exports = (_config, { strapi }) => {
  const redirects = ['/', '/index.html','/admin'].map((path) => ({
      method: 'GET',
      path,
      handler: (ctx) => ctx.redirect('/admin/content-manager'),
      config: { auth: false },
  }));

  strapi.server.routes(redirects);
};
```

> in config/middlewares.js

```
module.exports = [
  // all previous items ...
  { resolve: './src/middlewares/admin-redirect' }, // add this line
];
```

And all set!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Recently i’ve installed **strapi 4.16.2** for my client. My client want to see login page as root url. To do this i created a **global middleware using strapi cli**
Type **npm run strapi generate** in terminal then select **middleware** and give middleware name.
then select first option **Add middleware to root of project**
your global middleware is created in **src/middlewares/your_middleware.ts**
Now replace code below

```
    import { Strapi } from “@strapi/strapi”;
    export default (config, { strapi }: { strapi: Strapi }) => {

       return async (ctx, next) => {
      // use ctx.request to get request method and request path
       if (ctx.request.method === “GET” && ctx.request.path === “/”) {
        // use ctx.response.redirect(url,alt) to redirect root url to your admin url
       ctx.response.redirect(“/your_desire_url”, “/admin”);
      }
    await next();
   };
  };
```

To activate your middleware open **config/middlewares.ts** and add this line

**"global::your_middleware_name",**

Now run strapi app and see the result.